# select all the <P> outside a particular div (class)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all the `<p>` tag except the ones inside the `div` whose `class` is **div-class**. I tried the following and it didn't do the job.

```
<style>
    p:not(.div-class p) {
        color:red;
    }
</style>

<p> a p tag outside the div </p>
<div class="div-class">
    <p> a p tag inside the div </p>
</div>
<p> a p tag outside the div </p>
```

`p:not(.div-class p)` - this selector is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:not(.div-class) p` to select all `p` tags that are not a descendant of an element with `class='div-class'`. The `p:not(.div-class p)` selector does not work because the `:not` pseudo-class takes only [simple selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) as argument. You can refer [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) for the list of simple selectors.

```css
:not(.div-class) p {
  color: red;
}
.div-class p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>a p tag outside the div</p>
<div class="div-class">
  <p>a p tag inside the div</p>
</div>
<p>a p tag outside the div</p>
```

---

The approach provided by Shomz (in his deleted answer<sup>+</sup>) can also work for your case depending on the objective. If you can override the `color` for the more specific selector (the ones having the class) then that approach would be a bit more easier to understand and adopt.

However, if you can't override (or don't want to override) then this approach would be better. But the trouble is that if you don't override then `:not(.div-class) p` ends up selecting all `p` tags as `body` also doesn't have `class='div-class'`.

Selecting only the `p` which are not under an element with `class='div-class'` becomes very tricky when the `p` is not a direct child of element with `class='div-class'` and the `p` directly under `body` also need to be styled. The below snippet is a sample approach using a combination of selectors.

```css
body > p,
body > *:not(.div-class) p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>a p tag outside the div</p>
<div class="div-class">
  <p>a p tag inside the div</p>
</div>
<p>a p tag outside the div</p>

<div class="div-class">
  <div class="some-inner-class">
    <p>a p tag deep inside the div</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="some-other-class">
  <p>a p tag inside some other class div</p>
</div>

<div class="some-other-class">
  <div class="some-other-inner-class">
    <p>a p tag deep inside some other class div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>+ - The below is the approach that was **originally provided in Shomz' answer**. I am **including it here just for context**.</sup>

```css
p {
  color:red;
}
.div-class p {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p> a p tag outside the div </p>
<div class="div-class">
    <p> a p tag inside the div </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2013926: Thanks for accepting the answer. Both mine and Shomz' answer has advantages and I have just edited in the details into the answer.

Comment: .div-class p {  color: blue; } - when removed this line, the behavior is not what is expected.

Comment: @user2013926: Is the `p` always directly under the `div` with `class='div-class'`? Otherwise, the `body` is kind of affecting the working.

Comment: the `p` is inside the `div` with the `class='div-class'`. Not a direct child.

Comment: `body :not(.div-class) p` - is not doing the job, is it?. Btw, thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: No @user2013926 That wouldn't style the `p` tags that are directly under `body`.